# When are solutions to $Ax=b$ in the row span of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gradient-descent

Given an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ where $m < n$ and rows of $A$ are linearly independent, can we say that all possible solutions to $Ax=b$ are in the row span of $A$?

EDIT for context: We are using gradient descent to minimize $||Ax-b||^2$ and looking at $x_{t}$ at each $t$ step of the algorithm until convergence. The text claims that each of these $x_{t}$ is in the row span of $A$ but I am having trouble proving this.

Comment: What is the context and what did you attempted?

Comment: @Avenger Please see the edit for the question. It is in the context of gradient descent.

Comment: Looks good now.

Comment: $\pmatrix{1&2\cr}\pmatrix{x\cr y\cr}=7$ has the solution $(5,1)$ which is not in the rowpsace of $\pmatrix{1&2\cr}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson please do not push people into engaging with you. They are not expected to do so, specially if you push them to do so. Best,

Comment: @Pedro, is it really too much to ask that, when a user posts a question here, and one or more users post helpful comments and/or answers, that the user posting the question at least acknowledge those responses? And did you erase my vote-to-close, so now I can't vote-to-close it for another ten days?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am just asking you to be civil and patient. No, I did not erase your vote, there was no close vote at the moment I commented.

Comment: Under the stated conditions, there is exactly one solution of the equation $\ Ax=b\ $ whose transpose lies in the rowspace of $ \ A\ $.  Since the rows of $\ A\ $ are linearly independent, then the matrix $\ AA^\top\ $ is invertible.  The column vector
$$
x= A^\top\big(AA^\top\big)^{-1}b
$$
satisfies the equation $\ Ax=b\ $, and it is the only solution of that equation whose transpose lies in the rowspace of $\ A\ $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question for anyone who is also interested in this. In the general case, the solution does not have to be in the row span as in the example given by Gerry. However, there is more to the question if we look into the gradient descent algorithm.

The gradient of the function $F(x) = ||Ax-b||^2$ is $\nabla F(x) = 2A^T(Ax-b)$. This means the gradient is a linear combination of the rows of $A$. The gradient descent algorithm iteration step is: $x^{(t+1)} = x^{(t)} - \eta \nabla F(x^{(t)})$. Therefore, if the intial point $x^{(0)}$ is in the row span of the $A$ matrix, so will all the solutions found by the gradient descent, o.w. they will not be in the span.

Comment: $2A^t(Ax-b)$ is in the column space of $A^t$, not the row space.

Comment: fixed it, thank you. I meant to write a "linear combination of the rows of A" not $A^T$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\pmatrix{1&2\cr}$ so $A$ is a $1\times2$ matrix whose rows are linearly independent, and let $b=\pmatrix{7\cr}$, then $x=\pmatrix{5\cr1\cr}$ is a solution to $Ax=b$, but is not in the row space of $A$. So, the answer to the question is "No".